# How to map an array if you don't know what's being passed into it?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

sorry my formatting's wrong, I've never used stackoverflow but I'm struggling with an issue and I'm hoping someone can provide a little clarity.

I'm trying to build an application that displays all of an individual's favourite foods. For each individual, the program will generate a table, with the person's name at the top, and a list of their favourite foods underneath. It needs to accept any number of food items.

I can map my information out if I only have predetermined fields (favourite fruit / vegetable / dessert), but I don't want to rely on using "favFruit: user.favFruit", as this limits me to how many items i've already defined in my interface.

```
interface User {
    name: string;
    username: string;
    favourites: ???;  // maybe Array<any>?  
}

users.map(user => {
    user.name = [{ name: user.name, username: user.username }];
    user.favourites = [ { ??? } ];
    return user;
});
```

I could of course do the same thing I did when mapping out my user's name/username, but for this example I don't want to assume I know how many items are in my users' "favourites list", or what exactly they are. Any suggestions ?

Comment: okay, so your formatting is actually quiet good :). I'm just not exactly sure if I get your question. what does the `favourites` content look like? Is one favourite a string? Or a complete different interface (or class) for each kind? Let me know and I'll see if I can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define a separate `interface Favorite` if you're sure about the shape of the object i.e.

```
interface Favorite {
  type: string;
  name: string;
}
```

Then you can use `Array<Favorite>` in your `User` interface.

However, if the object shape cannot be determined then `Array<any>` will save you a lot of trouble.